# How to sort arrays inside an array?

Tags: php

I need to sort arrays inside an array of array based on one of the array's array value.

For example:

```
$data = array( array( 1, "Article One", 132, 12402773, 3 ),
               array( 2, "Article Two", 251, 12519283, 5 ),
               array( 3, "Article Three", 107, 12411321, 3 ),
               array( 4, "Article Four", 501, 12228135, 4 ) );
```

By default, if I print the 2nd element of each array:

- Article One
- Article Two
- Article Three
- Article Four

I need to sort it in a descending order by the 3rd element of the child-array.

So it would be like this:

- Article Four
- Article Two
- Article One
- Article Three

Because 501 > 251 > 132 > 107.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I typically use a `usort()` for this:

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    return ($a[2] > $b[2]);
}

usort($data, 'compare');
```

Comment: This is one of my favorite functions in php, especially with the uasort variant that preserves keys.

Comment: I Agree this is the way to go. usort/uasort dpending on the situation.

Comment: Better way would be to use an closure:
`usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[2] > $b[2];
});`

Comment: Yep - closure syntax is nice. A lot has changed since 2009!

Answer (score 2):

[array_multisort](http://www.php.net/array_multisort) :)