# PHP: Sort Array by subvalue

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort arrays inside an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930025/how-to-sort-arrays-inside-an-array)
>   [Sort an array by a child array's value in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672900/sort-an-array-by-a-child-arrays-value-in-php)

I've got an array that looks like this:

```
[0] => Array {
    [ID] => 1651,
    [DESCR] => "blabla",
    [SORTNR] => 1,
},
[1] => Array {
    [ID] => 456,
    [DESCR] => "bleble",
    [SORTNR] => 3,
},
[2] => Array {
    [ID] => 158,
    [DESCR] => "bliblablub",
    [SORTNR] => 2,
},
```

Now I want to sort the subarrays using the value of `[SORTNR]` descending, so here it should finally look like that:

```
[1] => Array {
    [ID] => 456,
    [DESCR] => "bleble",
    [SORTNR] => 3,
},
[2] => Array {
    [ID] => 158,
    [DESCR] => "bliblablub",
    [SORTNR] => 2,
},
[0] => Array {
    [ID] => 1651,
    [DESCR] => "blabla",
    [SORTNR] => 1,
},
```

How can I do that correctly in PHP? I tried some stuff now for four hours and I couldn't find any good solution....

Thx for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a['SORTNR'] == $b['SORTNR']) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a['SORTNR'] < $b['SORTNR']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($arr, 'cmp');
```

Code adapted from [PHP `uasort()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: For brevity, you can do `return $a['SORTNR'] - $b['SORTNR']` in your cmp() function

Answer (score 1):

If the subvalue you want to sort by is variable, you might also consider using `array_multisort()`. See Example #3: http://php.net/array_multisort